# Query to Salesforce returns columns out of order

Tags: salesforce, google-apps-script

I've developed a Google Apps script to pull some data from a custom object in Salesforce and have my columns in this order:

```
SELECT  Component__r.Name, Component__c, Product__c, Story_Name__c, Description__c, id ,  Product_Id__c, Priority__c , StoryName FROM Story__c WHERE Product_Id__c
```

However, my results into a Google Spreadsheet come in this order:

```
StoryName   Component__r    Component__c    Product__c  Product_Id__c   Priority__c Id  Description__c  Story_Name__c
```

I'm told that it's no unusual for SOQL queries to return data in a different order than the query.  Do anyone know of a method/function/process to use to get the columns to appear on the spreadsheet in the order of the query?  I'd like to do it prior to placing the columns on the spreadsheet, but if there's no other method, that's ok.

My data is pulled back in this function:

```
    function renderGridData(object, renderHeaders){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

 var data = [];
var sObjectAttributes = {};

//Need to always build headers for row length/rendering
var headers = buildHeaders(object.records);

 if(renderHeaders){  
  data.push(headers);
}

for (var i in object.records) {
var values = [];
for(var j in object.records[i]){
  if(j!="attributes"){
    values.push(object.records[i][j]);
  } else {
    var id = object.records[i][j].url.substr(object.records[i][j].url.length-18,18);
    //Logger.log(id);
    sObjectAttributes[id] = object.records[i][j].type;
  }
}
data.push(values);
}

Logger.log(sheet.getLastRow());
var destinationRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, headers.length);
 destinationRange.setValues(data);
 }
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: how are you actually executing the sql query?, rest api, ajax toolkit, something else ?

Comment: rest api.. code below
soql is passed in from another page

`function storyQuery(soql){
var sql = "SELECT  Component__r.Name, Component__c, Product__c, Story_Name__c, Description__c, id ,  Product_Id__c, Name FROM CMC_Story__c WHERE Product_Id__c = '"+soql+"' ORDER BY Component__c";

return fetch(**getRestEndpoint**()+"/services/data/v"+API_VERSION+"/"+"query?q="+sql);
}`
and 

`function **getRestEndpoint()**{
  var queryEndpoint = ".salesforce.com";
  var endpoint = getInstanceUrl().replace("api-","").match("https://[a-z0-9]*");
  return endpoint+queryEndpoint;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Partner SOAP APi is the only API that will try to preserve the field order from the query into the results structure.

For JSON based responses from the REST API, JSON specifically says that objects key/values are unordered, so a response that would preserve the order would need to use a different JSON structure (an array of key/value objects) which would be significantly more verbose.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear... but kinda what I expected :(